# Lp spaces and Hölder Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I have a question about Lp Spaces and Hölder Inequality.

My question is;

$f, g \in L_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\|f\|_{L_{3}(\mathbb{R})}=\|g\|_{L_{3}(\mathbb{R})}=2$ .

$$ 
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{2}(x) g(x) d x\right| \leq ?
$$

Here my opinion is  using the Hölder's Inequality in this question. Here's a link about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality
i know that there are also different versions of this inequality.i looked at some books. but i dont know how to apply this inequality on this question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hint: $1/3+2/3=1$.

Comment: thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int |f|^2|g|\leq\Big((\int|f|^3\Big)^{2/3}\big(\int|g|^3\Big)^{1/3}=\|f\|^2_3\|g\|_3=2^22=8$

Comment: that's a very good solution. i see it. thanks.